# PHP - Multiple variables in insert post array

Tags: php, wp-insert-post

I am currently creating a post programmatically, with the `wp_insert_post` function but am having some difficulties when adding two variables into the content part of the array. I would like to add `$_POST['poll-description']` as well as the code I am currently using `'[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'` to be the post content.

Is there any way I can use both of these in the following code?

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $current_user->ID,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>  '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'
    )
);
```

Would this work?

```
`post_content'  =>  $_POST['poll-description'] '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'`
```

Comment: what is $latest_pollid in your case. Where are you getting it. are you trying to insert a shortcode in post description along with content?

Comment: @WPTC-Troop latest poll id returns a number which yes makes up a shortcode in the content. I would like the content from `$_POST['poll-description'] ` to go before the shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $current_user->ID,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>  $_POST['poll-description'] . '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine(concatinate) posted description and your shortcode and then inser it in post.

```
$concat_content = $_POST['poll-description'].'[poll id="' . $latest_pollid . '"]';

$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $current_user->ID,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>  $concat_content
    )
);
```

If you find the above concatination confusing try the below

```
$concat_content = $_POST['poll-description'];
$concat_content .= '[poll id="' . $latest_pollid . '"]';
```

you can even insert a break tag between content and shortcode

Comment: I appreciate your answer but Omar's (above) seemed easier to implement so I chose his as correct.

Comment: oh ok. Jsut for your understanding I concatinated first.